# How to prevent system beep when creating multiple modal windows in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx-8

I'm facing an issue with `JavaFX 8u40` where creating two or more modal windows will cause a system beep on Mac OS X when closing the children windows.

The example below creates a modal window who's a child of another modal window. When I close the child modal window, my system beeps (the same way it beeps if I try to click on the parent modal window).

The problem seems related to `stage.initOwner(...)` where closing the child modal window tries to access the parent modal window before the `showAndWait()` loop is finished.

I just want to confirm I'm not doing anything wrong before filing a bug report.

```
public class TestDialog extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Button showModalButton = new Button("Show Modal Window");

        showModalButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            Stage modalStage = new Stage();

            modalStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            modalStage.initOwner(stage);

            Button createInnerModalButton = new Button("Create inner modal window");

            createInnerModalButton.setOnAction(e2 -> {
                Stage innerModalStage = new Stage();

                innerModalStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
                innerModalStage.initOwner(modalStage);

                Button closeInnerModalButton = new Button("Close");

                closeInnerModalButton.setOnAction(e3 -> {
                    innerModalStage.close();
                });

                VBox innerVBox = new VBox(
                    new Label("This is an inner modal window"), closeInnerModalButton);

                innerModalStage.setScene(new Scene(innerVBox));

                innerModalStage.showAndWait();
            });

            VBox vBox = new VBox(
                new Label("This is a modal window"), createInnerModalButton);

            modalStage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));

            modalStage.showAndWait();
        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(showModalButton));

        stage.show();
    }
}
```